# Can I access MSCrypto from a Web Worker in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, web-worker, webcrypto-api

IE11's Web Crypto is located inside of `window.msCrypto`, whereas for Firefox or Chrome, it's accessible in `window.crypto`.

Web Workers do not have access to the `window` context but, thankfully, Chrome and Firefox also expose the `crypto` variable in the Web Worker context (so, at the global level, you can use `this.crypto` to access the Web Crypto suite in a Web Worker). It would seem, however, that IE11 does *not* expose `this.msCrypto` in their Web Worker context.

Is that correct? Is there any way to use Web Crypto in an IE11 Web Worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"support Web Crypto API inside a Web Worker"* is an open issue on Microsoft developer site https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7607496/

> The Web Crypto API is not available inside a Web Worker. Both "self.crypto" and "self.msCrypto" are undefined inside a worker context.

I guess is the same issue for IE11 but I have not found documentation

In this [thread](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/13904769-support-web-crypto-api-inside-a-web-worker) suggests a workaround, changing from web worker thread to main thread to execute the WebCrypto operations. It is assumed that performance will be lost, and programming surely will be complex

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using ForgeJS as a backup. It's a lot slower than the native (for obvious reasons), but it works.